# How to insert into a DIY linked list implementation without copying?

Tags: c++, pointers

(Please don't ask me to just use the STL; I know I could, but I'm trying to write one myself to learn C++).

In every implementation of a linked list that I've seen so far, we have something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::insertAtFront(const T & data) {
    // Create a new ListNode on the heap:
    ListNode *node = new ListNode(data); // <----- LINE [*]

    // Re-point head, next, etc.
    // ...
}
```

My question is about line [*]. There is a potentially expensive copy assignment here (depending on how complex `T` is), because first we construct the new `ListNode` from `data`, and then we assign it to `*node`. I've checked this by writing my own assignment operator and stepping through the code.

Is there no way to just get `node` to point to the newly constructed `ListNode`?

Comment: You could avoid the copy by storing a reference or a pointer to the data. ***But*** (and this is very important) if the original data disappears (like its life-time ends, for example a local variable) then the reference or pointer becomes invalid. By storing a copy of the data you will always have a valid copy.

Comment: You could also solve it by using the ownership semantics of `std::shared_ptr` for the data. But then the original data must also be stored in a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: You could also implement a function with perfect forwarding, like the `emplace*` member functions in the standard library. Take a look at [`vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) for a nice example.

Comment: The list should be the owner of the data it stores, everything else will get quite confusing.  But there is nothing stopping you from using a `List<std::unique_ptr<MyLargeClass>>` to store only pointers.

Comment: `node` does just point to the newly constructed `ListNode`. It's constructing `ListNode` where copying of `data` happens, not in storing the pointer in `node` afterwards. You seem to believe a `T` is copied twice in your example; that's not the case.